# What are "cyclic" and "difference" matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm reading Gilbert's linear algebra book and there is an emphasis on difference (backward and forward according to the book) and cyclic matrices (it says that cyclic matrices don't have inverses, I didn't grasp that too). But I did not quite understand anything about them. Can someone explain it to a newcomer to the subject?

Comment: What's the title of the linear algebra book? The definitions of those matrices ought to have been explained somewhere in the book.

Comment: It's "Introduction To Linear Algebra, 4th edition". There is an explanation however it wasn't telling me the objective of the definition. It just turns out to be matrix exercise. But fortunately I got it in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cyclic, or circulant matrices are matrices of the following [form](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/4f93b3b2bc42921bfa0444d4acff88a6414bf251). So the rows and colums are obtained by cyclical permutation. Since the zero matrix and the identity matrix are cyclic, such matrices may or may not be invertible.

Link: [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zyklische_Matrix).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I finally got it. I didn't realize that identity and zero matrices share the same property too. It's a long way that I have in linear algebra...